# converting fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: c#

i am trying to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius. when i convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit i get correct results but when i try to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius i get wrong answer for instance if i type 98.7 Fahrenheit i get 81 degrees instead of 37.. does anyone know were i have gone wrong with my code

```
if (RadioFah.Checked) 
{
  {
    double F = 0;    

    F = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text) - 32 * 5/9);

    textBox2.Text = F.ToString() + " °C ";

    //String s = String.Format( "{0:0,00}", F );
    //F = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) -32 * (5/9);
    //TxtBoxCelsius.Text = s + " °C ";
  }
}
else if (RadioCelsius.Checked)
{
  //if (double.TryParse(textBox2.Text.Text, out C))
  {
    double C = 0;    

    C = (double.Parse(textBox2.Text) * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32);

    textBox1.Text = C.ToString("N1") + " °F ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a bracket

```
F = ((double.Parse(textBox1.Text) - 32) * 5/9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is not quite right. Try the bellow instead.

```
Celsius = (Fahrenheit  -  32)  x  5/9
```

The you have wrap the `Fahrenheit - 32` in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick helper method that you can use to get your values correctly.

```
static double ConvertToFahrenheit(double value)
{
    return ((value * 9) / 5) + 32;
}

static double ConvertToCelsius(double value)
{
    return ((value - 32) * 5) / 9;
}
```